# Acessibilidade inconsistente: tipo de parâmetro "valor" é menos acessível do que o método "valor"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

> Acessibilidade inconsistente: tipo de parâmetro "IClientManager" é menos acessível do que o método "ClienteController.ClientController(IclientManager, UserManager)

Controller:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    private readonly IClientManager _clientManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ClientController(   <-  Erro está aqui
        IClientManager clientManager,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _clientManager = clientManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

IClientManager:

```
internal interface IClientManager : IDisposable
{
    Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(ApplicationClient client);
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IClientManager, ClientManager>();
```

ClientManager:

```
public class ClientManager : IClientManager
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ClientManager(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(ApplicationClient client)
    {
        var result = await _context.Clientes.AddAsync(client);

        if (result.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return result.Entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a interface como `public`:

```
public interface IClientManager : IDisposable
```

Assim ela fica no mesmo nível de acessibilidade da classe "ClientController", que é `public`

Comment: Agora deu a seguinte mensagem `Mais de um modificador de proteção`

Comment: desculpe teve um erro na resposta, já corrigi

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente